# What documents can prove that I am a caregiver in my country of origin?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, applications, schengen-visas

In the Netherland Visa Documents checklist, it says to submit documents proving we will return to our country. One example it says, is: "A document proving you are a caregiver in your country of origin".

My husband is the sole caretaker of his aging grandmother. But how can he go about proving that? Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help to know which country you're from

Comment: The local nation's equivalent of the Netherlands Care Worker Qualification Level 3 certificate along with Netherlands Care Worker's Allowance remittances will qualify. I would emphatically not advise relying on attestations from the care receiver for plainly obvious reasons.

Comment: @eugene o Pakistan

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the country you're from and your exact situation, but a few ideas come to mind:

- A letter (possibly a notarized sworn oath) from the grandmother stating your friend is the sole caretaker. If the grandmother is not well enough to understand/sign documents, then there might be some documentation to that effect, naming your friend as a "substitute decision maker" or something like that (details var by country).
- A letter (possibly a notarized sworn oath) from a doctor taking care of the grandmother who knows about the situation (e.g. that the doctor always sees your friend taking the grandmother for visits, and that your friend pays for them)
- Summary of tax return from a tax authority, where your friend gets tax benefits for having the grandmother as a dependent. Possibly also the grandmother's tax documents showing no income of her own.
- Receipts for purchases paid for by your friend that are clearly intended for the grandmother
- In any case, even if you can't find anything official, don't leave this blank. Be creative - include statements from some people who know about the situation, etc.

Also, ideally try to prove not just the financial side of things, but also the time commitment your friend is putting into taking care of the grandmother. I know it's more difficult to prove but it's worth trying (financial commitments can be met by sending money from another country, but time commitments can't, so it's more valuable to show a time commitment for immigration purposes).

Comment: Good idea. I think we can get her geriatrics doctor to testify perhaps. Thank you.